# Dim screen with battery indicator and mousewheel on elementary os

Tags: brightness, battery

I know that on my other ubuntu installations (kubuntu, lubuntu, xubuntu and mint) there was this neat little tweak on by default where when my cursor is hovering the battery indicator icon, i could dim or brighten my laptop display with my mousewheel.

Sadly, in elementary os it seems this is deactivated. How can I activate it?

Using elementary OS 0.3.1 Freya (64-bit) (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Questions on elementary OS should be asked at the [elementaryos.se] site.

Answer (score 1):

The power indicator (package `wingpanel-indicator-power`) in elementary OS is not the same as the battery indicator of Ubuntu.

This functionality does not exist here, so you cannot "activate" it.